# org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext

Tags: spring-boot

I migrated an old jsp project from spring-boot 2.7.5 to spring-boot-3.0.0-RC1 without problems.
However, using 3.0.0-RC2 or 3.0.0 causes problems.
Everything is fine when running from within Eclipse, but running the war file standalone from the command line causes an Exception:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.0)

25.11.2022 10:05:09 INFO  .l.bokaskra2.web.Bokaskra2WebApplication:51   : Starting Bokaskra2WebApplication v2.1.0-SNAPSHOT using Java 17 with PID 26724 (E:\Project_bins\Bokaskra2\bokaskra2-web-2.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war started by perryirrep in E:\Project_bins\Bokaskra2)
25.11.2022 10:05:09 INFO  .l.bokaskra2.web.Bokaskra2WebApplication:630  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
25.11.2022 10:05:10 INFO  .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate:294  : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
25.11.2022 10:05:10 INFO  .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate:138  : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
25.11.2022 10:05:10 INFO  .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate:208  : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 36 ms. Found 8 JPA repository interfaces.
25.11.2022 10:05:10 INFO  .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate:294  : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
25.11.2022 10:05:10 INFO  .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate:138  : Bootstrapping Spring Data Elasticsearch repositories in DEFAULT mode.
25.11.2022 10:05:10 INFO  .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate:208  : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 14 ms. Found 0 Elasticsearch repository interfaces.
25.11.2022 10:05:10 INFO  .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate:294  : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
25.11.2022 10:05:10 INFO  .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate:138  : Bootstrapping Spring Data Reactive Elasticsearch repositories in DEFAULT mode.
25.11.2022 10:05:10 INFO  .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate:208  : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 2 ms. Found 0 Reactive Elasticsearch repository interfaces.
25.11.2022 10:05:11 INFO  i.l.bokaskra2.web.config.WebConfig      :55   : AJP Enabled on port 8903
25.11.2022 10:05:11 INFO  boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer:114  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8903 (http)
25.11.2022 10:05:11 INFO  org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProtocol    :173  : Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8903"]
25.11.2022 10:05:11 INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService:173  : Starting service [Tomcat]
25.11.2022 10:05:11 INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine :173  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.1]
25.11.2022 10:05:12 ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase  :175  : A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[/bokaskra2]]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:252)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:926)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:485)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:129)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:110)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:486)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:210)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:183)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:578)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
        at is.landsbokasafn.bokaskra2.web.Bokaskra2WebApplication.main(Bokaskra2WebApplication.java:33)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[/bokaskra2]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:831)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.getManifestName(ZipFile.java:1057)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.getManifestName(ZipFile.java:1100)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getManEntry(JarFile.java:937)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.checkForSpecialAttributes(JarFile.java:1000)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.isMultiRelease(JarFile.java:389)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:68)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:41)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:393)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:328)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:271)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:234)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:83)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5153)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 43 common frames omitted
25.11.2022 10:05:12 ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase  :175  : A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:252)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:926)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:485)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:129)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:110)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:486)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:210)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:183)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:578)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
        at is.landsbokasafn.bokaskra2.web.Bokaskra2WebApplication.main(Bokaskra2WebApplication.java:33)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:938)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[/bokaskra2]]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
        ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[/bokaskra2]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:831)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.getManifestName(ZipFile.java:1057)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.getManifestName(ZipFile.java:1100)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getManEntry(JarFile.java:937)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.checkForSpecialAttributes(JarFile.java:1000)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.isMultiRelease(JarFile.java:389)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:68)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:41)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:393)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:328)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:271)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:234)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:83)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5153)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 43 common frames omitted
25.11.2022 10:05:12 INFO  org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProtocol    :173  : Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8903"]
25.11.2022 10:05:12 INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService:173  : Stopping service [Tomcat]
25.11.2022 10:05:12 INFO  org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProtocol    :173  : Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8903"]
25.11.2022 10:05:12 WARN  ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext:592  : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
25.11.2022 10:05:12 INFO  .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger:82   :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
25.11.2022 10:05:12 ERROR g.springframework.boot.SpringApplication:820  : Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:578)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
        at is.landsbokasafn.bokaskra2.web.Bokaskra2WebApplication.main(Bokaskra2WebApplication.java:33)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:148)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:110)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:486)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:210)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:183)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161)
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:938)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:252)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:926)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:485)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:129)
        ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
        ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:938)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[/bokaskra2]]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
        ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[/bokaskra2]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:831)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.getManifestName(ZipFile.java:1057)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.getManifestName(ZipFile.java:1100)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getManEntry(JarFile.java:937)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.checkForSpecialAttributes(JarFile.java:1000)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.isMultiRelease(JarFile.java:389)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:68)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:41)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:393)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:328)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:271)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:234)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:83)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5153)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 43 common frames omitted
```

```
<dependencies>
     <!-- Spring Boot managed dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        
    <!-- Other dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>quick-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.3</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
            <groupId>jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
            <artifactId>saxon</artifactId>
            <version>8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
            <artifactId>saxon-dom</artifactId>
            <version>8.7</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- Other dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
      <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>net.bull.javamelody</groupId>
          <artifactId>javamelody-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
          <version>1.87.0</version>
        </dependency>
    
  </dependencies>
```

I checked dependency conflicts but found none.
When I remove the tomcat-embed-jasper dependency, the app starts ok, but of course the jsp pages don´t work then.
Any ideas what´s going on ?

Comment: There appears to be a problem with a jar file that Jasper is scanning. Perhaps the upgrade downloaded a new version of that jar and it is corrupted? It may be worth purging Maven's local cache and trying again. You could also use the debugger to found out which jar is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Andy , you pointed me in the right direction.
Played around with server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns property and noticed that with a value of "*" the app started, but with "*.jar" did not start.
So I solved the problem by using a custom ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory:

```
@Bean
public ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory webServerFactory() {
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
        var js = ((StandardJarScanner) context.getJarScanner());
        js.setScanClassPath(false);
        }
    };
    return factory;
}
```

This works, though I have no idea why